# Регулярка. Парсинг размера

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть такая регулярка:

```
/(\d{2,4})+|\s+(x|-|na|х|\s|на|)+|\s+(\d{2,4})/
```

Она на ура отрабатывает парсер размера `100 на 60` и т.п.

Но почему то она срабатывает и на строку: `100 руб`

Как ее доработать чтобы она четко работала: цифры (разделитель) цена.

Спасибо. P.S: язык Php :)

Comment: а зачем вы `|` поставили? Это же ИЛИ. Вот оно и выбирает. Пробуйте пользоватся http://regexr.com например. помогает)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю

```
'/(\d+)\s*([\p{Pd}xх]|na|на)\s*(\d+)/u'
```

[См. демо выражения](https://regex101.com/r/l8lfml/2)

- `(\d+)` - Группа 1: одна и более цифр
- `\s*` - 0+ пробельных символов
- `([\p{Pd}xх]|na|на)` - разные дефисы (`\p{Pd}`), `x`, `х`, `na` или `на`
- `\s*`  - 0+ пробельных символов
- `(\d+)` - Группа 3: одна и более цифр

Если числа могут быть дробными, можно добавить `(?:[.,]\d+)?` после `\d+`:

```
/(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)\s*([\p{Pd}xх]|na|на)\s*(\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?)/u
```

[PHP:](https://ideone.com/dubnZV)

```
$re = '/(\d+)\s*([\p{Pd}xх]|na|на)\s*(\d+)/u';
$str = '100 на 60, 100 руб';
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    echo $m[1] . ", " . $m[2] . ", " . $m[3] . "\n";
}
// => 100, на, 60
```

Comment: Благодарю.!!!!!

Comment: Рад помочь. Пожалуйста, примите ответ, если он решает Вашу проблему (см. [Что делать когда кто-то ответил на мой вопрос?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: А подскажите, пожалуйста, простецкий способ разделить цифры  и буквы пробелом ? 

Строка привет1243  => привет 1243

Comment: `preg_replace('~(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)~', ' ', $s)`

Comment: И еще. Как мне указать "может быть пробел, а может быть его и не быть" грамотно ?

Comment: Используя квантификаторы: `\s?` - 1 или 0 пробелов, `\s*` - 0 и более пробелов.